# SVG path animation jump

Tags: animation, svg, smil

I want to animate the SVG path. I have the same points with the same bezier settings. When I move 2 points to the rectangle center, the animation is jumpy and not smooth.

I found that if these points aren't initially at the straight path, so the animation is smooth! It looks like a bug(

Please take a look at the code below that demonstrates the issue or check it at [jsfiddle](http://%20%20%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/q8xm1jrL/5/)

```html
<p>
    Jumpy animation
    </p>
    <svg
          width="200px"
          height="133px"
          viewBox="0 0 200 133"
          version="1.1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#616161" stroke-width="4">
            <animate
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              fill="freeze"
              attributeName="d"
              dur="1s"
              values="
                  M194.002061,2 L6.04008364,2 C4.93732761,2 3.93634261,2.44884122 3.21071297,3.17293744 C2.4868279,3.89529278 2.03648273,4.89249429 2.03520721,5.99450035 C2.03520685,5.99479332 2.00668933,27.8652779 2.0009858,56.2997166 L2.00099044,75.7284095 C2.00633859,102.416639 2.03165325,123.946234 2.03537152,126.995569 C2.03658483,128.103158 2.48473311,129.104131 3.20922748,129.828298 C3.93400562,130.552748 4.93501692,131 6.04008364,131 L194.002061,131 C195.103988,131 196.103728,130.551165 196.827984,129.826994 C197.551106,129.103958 198,128.10572 198,127.002769 L198,6.00648893 C198,4.90021634 197.552004,3.89812727 196.827599,3.1726896 C196.10443,2.44849045 195.105573,2 194.002061,2 Z;
                  M194.002061,2 L6.04008364,2 C5.10902172,2 4.31668949,2.30236194 3.85350371,2.90851535 C3.39667486,3.50634969 3.31057704,4.33560556 3.54696163,5.22117815 C3.86947297,6.28159062 12,33.3316693 12,66 C12,98.5769844 3.88123574,126.502941 3.52148092,127.724391 C3.29190054,128.632682 3.3847554,129.480677 3.85171612,130.090231 C4.31671586,130.697225 5.10716799,131 6.04008364,131 L194.002061,131 C194.93514,131 195.729297,130.695801 196.194861,130.088316 C196.654,129.489213 196.743593,128.658124 196.508976,127.7702 C196.191061,126.712841 188,99.1556305 188,66 C188,32.9864348 196.081953,6.47466459 196.47066,5.21865408 C196.704535,4.32673476 196.625248,3.49294113 196.169159,2.8935357 C195.712562,2.29346354 194.928003,2 194.002061,2 Z;
                  "
            />
          </path>
        </svg>
        
        <p>Smooth animation</p>
    <svg
          width="200px"
          height="133px"
          viewBox="0 0 200 133"
          version="1.1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#616161" stroke-width="4">
            <animate
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              fill="freeze"
              attributeName="d"
              dur="1s"
              values="
    
                  M194.002061,2 L6.04008364,2 C5.01864027,2 4.13094436,2.38711966 3.54504923,3.05900142 C2.96245482,3.72709805 2.69875705,4.65340158 2.8319904,5.66241724 C2.94868384,6.43004297 7,33.3049889 7,66 C7,98.6124871 2.94857998,126.406308 2.81356562,127.323487 C2.6863776,128.338493 2.95459365,129.271195 3.54304738,129.943133 C4.13015485,130.613535 5.01675297,131 6.04008364,131 L194.002061,131 C195.024357,131 195.913135,130.612952 196.500141,129.941232 C197.083085,129.274159 197.347862,128.349268 197.215493,127.34166 C197.098926,126.569179 193,99.1791137 193,66 C193,32.9505546 197.046245,6.61163817 197.194423,5.65815893 C197.326276,4.64771432 197.066516,3.7189792 196.484282,3.05011469 C195.903212,2.38258626 195.021469,2 194.002061,2 Z;
                  M194.002061,2 L6.04008364,2 C5.10902172,2 4.31668949,2.30236194 3.85350371,2.90851535 C3.39667486,3.50634969 3.31057704,4.33560556 3.54696163,5.22117815 C3.86947297,6.28159062 12,33.3316693 12,66 C12,98.5769844 3.88123574,126.502941 3.52148092,127.724391 C3.29190054,128.632682 3.3847554,129.480677 3.85171612,130.090231 C4.31671586,130.697225 5.10716799,131 6.04008364,131 L194.002061,131 C194.93514,131 195.729297,130.695801 196.194861,130.088316 C196.654,129.489213 196.743593,128.658124 196.508976,127.7702 C196.191061,126.712841 188,99.1556305 188,66 C188,32.9864348 196.081953,6.47466459 196.47066,5.21865408 C196.704535,4.32673476 196.625248,3.49294113 196.169159,2.8935357 C195.712562,2.29346354 194.928003,2 194.002061,2 Z;
                  "
            />
          </path>
        </svg>
```

```
<p>How to create smooth animation that starts at the same point as the first rectangle? </p>
```

Comment: For a smooth animation you must have the same number of path commands. They must also be the same type in the same order. I imagine your paths are simply not similar enough. (Path commands are letters).

Comment: I created that path by duplicating the same shape and just moving 2 points. Probably while  export path shape from the graphic software it automatically removes 2 points from the middle of path. In that case I see no way to make that animation smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that when dragging nodes in the vector editor, the type of nodes changes
Therefore, smooth animation is not obtained even if the number of node points is equal in the initial and final paths of the shape.

It remained to solve the problem of how to prevent the type node points from changing when dragging.
I found that most often the type of **automatically smoothed points** changes to other types of node points
Therefore, I tried to avoid using this type of node points.
I first created a rectangle with concave sides and then transformed these sides into straight lines.

With this technique, the type of node points did not change and the animation became smooth.

```html
<p>Smooth animation</p>
    <svg
          width="200px"
          height="133px"
          viewBox="0 0 200 133"
          version="1.1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#616161" stroke-width="4">
            <animate
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              fill="freeze"
              attributeName="d"
              dur="3s"
              values="    
            m5.8 127.8c-1.6-1.6-3-3.7-3-6 0-14.3-0.7-34.2-0.7-53.7 0-18.3 0.7-55.2 0.7-55.2 0 0 0.1-6.5 2.1-8.6C6.7 2.5 12.3 2.3 12.3 2.3H187.9c0 0 4.6 0.9 6.2 2.4 2.9 2.8 2.9 8.3 2.9 8.3 0 0-0.5 36.9-0.5 55.2 0 19.4 0.5 35.9 0.5 53.7 0 2.4-1.3 4.7-3 6.4-1.6 1.6-6 2.7-6 2.7H12.3c0 0-4.8-1.5-6.5-3.2z;
            m5.8 127.8c-1.6-1.6-3-3.7-3-6 0-14.3 9.3-34.2 9.3-53.7 0-18.3-9.3-55.2-9.3-55.2 0 0 0.1-6.5 2.1-8.6C6.7 2.5 12.3 2.3 12.3 2.3H187.9c0 0 4.6 0.9 6.2 2.4 2.9 2.8 2.9 8.3 2.9 8.3 0 0-8.5 36.9-8.5 55.2 0 19.4 8.5 35.9 8.5 53.7 0 2.4-1.3 4.7-3 6.4-1.6 1.6-6 2.7-6 2.7H12.3c0 0-4.8-1.5-6.5-3.2z;
                m5.8 127.8c-1.6-1.6-3-3.7-3-6 0-14.3-0.7-34.2-0.7-53.7 0-18.3 0.7-55.2 0.7-55.2 0 0 0.1-6.5 2.1-8.6C6.7 2.5 12.3 2.3 12.3 2.3H187.9c0 0 4.6 0.9 6.2 2.4 2.9 2.8 2.9 8.3 2.9 8.3 0 0-0.5 36.9-0.5 55.2 0 19.4 0.5 35.9 0.5 53.7 0 2.4-1.3 4.7-3 6.4-1.6 1.6-6 2.7-6 2.7H12.3c0 0-4.8-1.5-6.5-3.2z"
            />
          </path>
        </svg>
```